# jqgrid - dynamically change mask based on a previous column value

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js

In column 1, are the phone types.  In column 2 the phone numbers.

{ name: 'PhoneTypeId', index: 'PhoneTypeId', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: true},

{ name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).mask("(999) 999-9999"); }, dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function (e) { hasChanges=true } }]}, editrules:{required: true}, sortable: true },

I'd like to dynamically change the mask based on the type of phone.  Is this possible?

My data is json serialized objects:
        datatype: "local",
        data: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Phones)
        editurl: 'clientArray'

Thanks,
Gen

Answer (score 0):

You can add change event (using dataInit) of the phone type and based on this you can change the mask (if this plugin allows this). Initially when you start editing (depending on the edit type - form edit or inline edit) you can use some events before editing by example beforeShowForm for form edit or beforeEditRow for inline edit. If you use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net) you can look at the [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/)

EDIT:

In case the field phonetype is not editable by the user then

```
{ name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 150, editable: true, 
    editoptions:{ 
        dataInit: function (elem, options) { 
           // use the id of the row
           var id = options.rowId;
           // content of the phonetype cell
           var phonetypeval = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', id, 'PhoneTypeId')
           if( phonetypeval === 'something') {
               mask = 'mask1';
           } else {
               mask = 'mask2';
           }
           $(elem).mask(mask); 
        }, 
        dataEvents: [{
            type: 'change', fn: function (e) { hasChanges=true } }
        ]}
    , editrules:{required: true}, 
    sortable: true}
```

Note that this code is valid for inline and form edit.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  Since I am using jqGrid 4.4.4, I think beforeEditRow does not exist.  I am not sure how to: "You can add change event (using dataInit) of the phone type and based on this you can change the mask (if this plugin allows this)."   How in code do I write this change event on PhoneType whereby it changes the mask on the next column (adjacent) ?

Comment: I'm going to prepare a example, but need to know which editing module is used? One more question - Is phone type field editable? I see it is hidden, but editable - edit:true, which will not make the field editable since it is hidden.

Comment: This is inline editing.  Correct, the type is hidden, not edited.

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'rowId' of undefined or null reference.  The debugger shows the "options" param as undefined.

Comment: OK. the parameter is not available in 4.4 version. Try this `var id = this.p.selrow;`

Comment: This shows id to be "null".  I had thought to try something like this too, to get the "selected row", but w/ no success.  What is "p" ? --> this.p

Comment: Use `var id = $('#gridid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');`

Comment: That's what I had tried.  The nuance then becomes after page ready/done.  the first click on the edit icon this [ var id = $('#gridid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); alert(id); ] alerts "null".  Then cancel edit, then hit the edit icon again it has the id!  There is something on the first invocation of the edit row taht this does not react correctly!?

Comment: Try to enclose this code in setTimeout function - i.e `dataInit : function(elem) { setTimeout( function(){ ..  //code here }, 200); },`

Comment: I have look into the code of jqGrid 4.4 - the problem here is that in this version the dataInit is called before to put the input element into the DOM. Instead of this the id should be obtained with getGridParam, since a row selection is performed. I will try to help, but it is a good idea to post your full code or prepare a demo in jsfiddle.net by example. I recommend you to upgrade to the latest of: either of free-jqGrid or Guriddo jqGrid, which is commercial now.

Comment: Thank you Tony.  Yes, even after successfully getting the id, like your finding, you cannot call 'getCell' either at this stage according to docs.  Is 4.7 going to be totally backward compatible?  I've been looking at what is given, the 'elem'.  It seems like that is possible to get up-to-date info of the dom (prev, parents, etc.), though, I have not completed it.  I'll try a jsfiddle.